# vb.net code to close another form if it is open

Tags: vb.net

This is pretty rudimentary, but I can't figure it out.

I want to programmatically close form1 when form2 closes, if form1 is still open. Form2 was opened by a command button on form1.

The code on Form1 that opens Form2 is:

```
Dim frm As New form2
frm.Show()
```

What's the best way when Form2 closes to close any open copies of Form1 that are open, also?

Comment: Just add an event handler for the FormClosed event and call Me.Close()

Comment: I'm trying to add an event handler to form2 so when it closes, it closes form1 (if form1 is open). Me.Close() would close form2, wouldn't it? How would I close form1?

Comment: No, the code belongs in the Form1 class.  Hard to see why this is a problem, maybe you don't know the AddHandler statement yet.  Put  AddHandler frm.FormClosed, AddressOf(yadayada) as the second statement in the snippet you posted.  And add the yadayada method, all it needs to do is Me.Close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle your two forms independently, you need to watch over them from a third form or class. So my suggestion would be to create both of them in this third class, and pass a reference of the second form to the first form so it can then open it. This way:

```
Public Class MyHelper

    Public Sub CreateForms()
        Dim form2 as New Form2()
        AddHandler form2.Closed, AddressOf Form2_OnClosed

        ‘ Create as many copies as you need
        Dim form1 as New Form1(form2)
        form1.Show()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Form2_OnClosed(sender as object, e as EventArgs) 
        ‘ Same code for each form1 that has been created and opened.
        If (form1.IsOpen) Then form1.Close()
    End Sub

End Class


Public Class Form1

    Private _form2 as Form2

    Public Property IsOpen as Boolean = false

    Public Sub New(form2 as Form2)
        _form2 = form2
    End Sub

    Protected Sub MyButton_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) handles MyButton.Click
        ‘ You open your form here or wherever you want (even on the constructor)
        _form2.Show()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Me_OnClosed(sender as object, e as EventArgs) handles Me.Closed
        Me.IsOpen = false
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Me_OnShown(sender as object, e as EventArgs) handles Me.Shown
        Me.IsOpen = true
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: So how can I tell if the form is open or not? What if the user might have closed it after form2 was opened?

Answer (score 1):

Add this reference to make it work.

```
Imports System.Linq

If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Form1).Any Then
   MsgBox("Form1 is open")
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Supposing you have 3 forms and want to close the other two on button click

```
Private Sub EMPLEADOToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EMPLEADOToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of BUSCAR_INDEX).Any Then
        BUSCAR_INDEX.Close()
    ElseIf Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of MIEMBROS_INDEX).Any Then
        MIEMBROS_INDEX.Close()
    End If
    EMP_INDEX.Show()
    EMP_INDEX.EmpIDTextBox.Text = EmpIDTextBox.Text
End Sub
```